# Robotium 5.2.1 example NotePad

Tags: java, android, junit, robotium

In

```
public void testAddNote() throws Exception {
```

i added

```
solo.unlockScreen();
solo.waitForText("Add note");
solo.clickOnMenuItem("Add note");
```

And I can see the "Add note" menu item in Emulator when execution Android JUnit Test!

But The test fails with:

```
junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: Text string: 'Add note' is not found!
at com.robotium.solo.Clicker.clickOnText(Clicker.java:447)
at com.robotium.solo.Clicker.clickOnMenuItem(Clicker.java:287)
at com.robotium.solo.Solo.clickOnMenuItem(Solo.java:921)
at com.robotium.test.NotePadTest.testAddNote(NotePadTest.java:48)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at android.test.InstrumentationTestCase.runMethod(InstrumentationTestCase.java:214)
at android.test.InstrumentationTestCase.runTest(InstrumentationTestCase.java:199)
at android.test.ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2.runTest(ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2.java:192)
at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:191)
at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:176)
at android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner.onStart(InstrumentationTestRunner.java:555)
at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:1701)
```

Please help me out here.

Thanks
Gerrit

!SOLVED! I changed from the latest Wearable 4.4W Emulator to a Telephon 4.4.2 Emulator. Now it runs fine in Android w/ Robotium Testcases! Thanks all!

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://code.google.com/p/robotium/downloads/detail?name=ExampleTestProject_v5.0.1.zip&can=2&q=) test project and go through this [link](https://code.google.com/p/robotium/wiki/RobotiumTutorials), it should help you.

Comment: ooooh i think your problem is, that the text is inside a menu item and not plain text

Comment: why not use  solo.searchButton("Add note"); =?

Comment: thanks for `solo.searchButton("Add note")`. It is much faster now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

!SOLVED! I changed from the latest Wearable 4.4W Emulator to a Telephone 4.4.2 Emulator. Now it runs fine in Android w/ Robotium Testcases! Thanks all!